# azure speech to text with audio url

Tags: javascript, azure, botframework, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

Hi I have tried speech to text with audio files using azure speech to text and everything is working correctly. Can some one guide me how to do the speech to text in azure using audio url. I'm using the REST API.

Comment: what have you done so far? Have you looked at the documentation? See "batch transcription" feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To second what Nicolas said: if you'd like to use a REST API to convert audio URLs to text, batch transcription is the way to go.

Details on fetching the audio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription-audio-data

And a JS sample for batch: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/batch/js/node

Answer (score 1):

```
public async Task<List<AudioTranscriptDto>> GenerateAudioTranscript(string audioFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(_configuration["SpeechCognitive:SubscriptionKey"], _configuration["SpeechCognitive:Region"]);
        speechConfig.RequestWordLevelTimestamps();
        speechConfig.OutputFormat = Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.OutputFormat.Detailed;

        var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(audioFilePath);
        var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        var speechRecognizerWaiter = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var transcript = new List<AudioTranscriptDto>();
        int sequenceNumber = 1;
        recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
            {
                string text = e.Result.Text;
                var duration = e.Result.Duration;
                long offset = e.Result.OffsetInTicks;

                var startTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(offset);
                var endTime = startTime + duration;
                var srtBlock = $"{sequenceNumber}\n{FormatTimeSpan(startTime)} --> {FormatTimeSpan(endTime)}\n{text}\n\n";

                transcript.Add(new AudioTranscriptDto
                {
                    SequenceNumber = sequenceNumber,
                    StartTime = FormatTimeSpan(startTime),
                    EndTime = FormatTimeSpan(endTime),
                    Text = text
                });
                sequenceNumber++;
            }
        };

        recognizer.SessionStarted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------> started");
        };

        recognizer.SessionStopped += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------> stooped");
            speechRecognizerWaiter.SetResult("Recognition completed");
        };

        await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();
        var str = await speechRecognizerWaiter.Task;
        await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();

        return transcript;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}

static string FormatTimeSpan(TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    return $"{timeSpan.Hours:D2}:{timeSpan.Minutes:D2}:{timeSpan.Seconds:D2},{timeSpan.Milliseconds:D3}";
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35610667)